# Change bluetooth mac address in Raspbian

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, raspbian

hi i need to change the bluetooth mac address from my device. i've download the bdaddr utility from [here](http://blog.petrilopia.net/linux/change-your-bluetooth-device-mac-address/)! and i compiled it.

Then...

```
wget -U "Mozilla" http://www.petrilopia.net/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/bdaddrtar.bz2
...
mv bdaddrtar.bz2 bdaddr.tar.bz2
tar xvjf bdaddr.tar.bz2
cd bdaddr 
sudo apt-get install libbluetooth-dev
...
make
```

...

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/bdaddr $ hcitool dev
Devices:
    hci0    00:1F:81:00:08:30
pi@raspberrypi ~/bdaddr $ hciconfig
    hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:1F:81:00:08:30  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 180:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:2296 acl:0 sco:0 events:100 errors:0
    TX bytes:1081 acl:0 sco:0 commands:98 errors:0
pi@raspberrypi ~/bdaddr $ sudo ./bdaddr -i hci0 00:1F:81:00:48:30
Manufacturer:   Cambridge Silicon Radio (10)
Device address: 00:1F:81:00:08:30
New BD address: 00:1F:81:00:48:30

Can't write new address
```

Why can't i write the address? some idea?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bdaddr utility is not part of the bluez package because it uses manufacturer specific code and as such does not work on all devices.

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-925611.html